# How to stop apparmor spew in the logs

Tags: apparmor, dmesg

I try to keep my dmesg clean, so I can see the signal in the noise.
However, I am annoyed by the spamming that app armor does in the logs:

```
[74339.538450] audit: type=1400 audit(1620404490.953:75): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.chromium.chromium" name="/run/udev/data/c509:6" pid=33938 comm="ThreadPoolForeg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

How do I stop these messages from being created?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To really stop those messages, I think you'll have to change the AppArmor profiles. An easier solution that worked for me is to install auditd (`sudo apt install auditd`). If the audit demon is running, the messages are still produced, but they'll end up in the audit log (in `var/log/audit/audit.log`) and don't clutter your `dmesg` output any more.